# Why was `react-native-reanimated` removed from the interpolators?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/282f62c2584413b96c21f34b8759999494cec60a

I was just wondering, and I also couldn't find the reason anywhere. I can't find the roadmap issue for v5 (I'm assuming there was one, couldn't remember)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long version: https://twitter.com/satya164/status/1212082997765251072

tldr; Reanimated 1 has bad performance on initial render, which didn't give acceptable startup perf with Stack.